# Using Google api to get State/Country suggestions for city

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

I have a list of North American cities that are inconsistently paired with provinces and countries. Example:

- Calgary AB Canada
- CALGARY Alberta - CA
- Calgary Canada

I would like to format each city so it follows a consistent pattern. So that it includes City State/Province and Country. Like:

- Calgary Alberta Canada

I've tried using Google's Places API to get suggestions for possible formating but all I've been able to achieve is a sort of validation that indicates if such a city exists. I was wondering if someone who has worked extensively with Google API's can guide me on how I can get City/Province-State/Country suggestions ( possibly in JSON format) from a city input.

```
 var input = "City Name";
 var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
 service.getQueryPredictions({ input: input }, callback});
```

I tried looking into [geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1#GeocodingRequests) but that seems to bring back lat/log information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Geocoding API is what you want.

Try

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Calgary,%20Alberta&sensor=false
```

it'll return fully formatted address info in several ways (split by administrative level, formatted as an address, etc.)

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Calgary",
               "short_name" : "Calgary",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Division No. 6",
               "short_name" : "Division No. 6",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Alberta",
               "short_name" : "AB",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kanada",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Calgary, Alberta, Kanada",
```

The `formatted_address` component is in German ("Kanada") because my browser's language is German.  You can define which language the output should be in using the `hl` parameter.

Note that technically, according to their T&C, using the Geocoding API is permitted only to prepare data for display on a Google Map.